# Creating Lua Functions to avoid code repetition in the same file

Tags: function, lua, arguments, string-matching

I am having following type of code ,that I used 6-7 times in the same file:

```
str=(line):match("constraints(.*)end")
for split in string_gsplit(str, '\n', true) do
if
string.match(split,'%a+')
then
a=(split):match("(.-)%s")
a=null_value(a)
b=(split):match("tx=(%a+)")
b=null_value(b)
c=(split):match("ty=(%a+)")
c=null_value(c)
d=(split):match("tz=(%a+)")
d=null_value(d)
e=(split):match("rx=(%a+)")
e=null_value(e)
f=(split):match("ry=(%a+)")
f=null_value(f)
g=(split):match("rz=(%a+)")
g=null_value(g)
print(a..b..c..d..e..f..g)
end 
end
```

To avoid repetition, I want to use functions in this. Such that I call the function only and I get the print results.
Since the arguments are different in every match function.
The strings given in double quotes ("abc") are different and can't be same.
Pls help me in creating a function.

I tried of creating it. Have a look:

```
function f(s)
assert(type(s) == "string")
str=(line):match(s)
for split in string_gsplit(str, '\n', true) do
if
string.match(split,'%a+')
then
end
end
return s
end
```

for calling the same function, I type:

```
s="constraints(.*)end"
f(s)
```

Comment: You should really start indenting your code if you want to keep it clear (for us as well as for yourself). Take a look at the [Lua Style Guide](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide).

Comment: Also give your variables and functions meaningful names. Calling them a,b,c and f makes your code very obscure. Call them something that explains what they contain, like surname, full_name_with_address and separate_address_and_fullname.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you're asking for. What duplication are you trying to remove? The list of `split:match`-`null_value` lines? You could do that in a loop by putting the patterns in a list:

```
local patterns = { "(.-)%s", "tx=(%a+)", "ty=(%a+)", "tz=(%a+)", "rx=(%a+)", "ry=(%a+)", "rz=(%a+)" }
local results = {}
for i,pattern in ipairs(patterns) do
    results[#results+1] = null_value( split:match(pattern) )
end
print(table.concat(results))
```

---

Tips:

1. You're putting variables in parenthesis arbitrarily and unnecessarily. `split:match(patt)` means the same thing as `(split):match(patt)`.
2. You're not using locals. The larger the scope of your variables, the greater the risk that changes in one part of your code will adversly affect some distant, unrelated part of your code, which is hard to reason about and debug. You should make variables local whenever possible, which in Lua also happens to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions on the string table that work like match and find like so:

```
function string.ReadArgument( str, pattern )
  return null_value( str:match( pattern ) )
end
```

Which you would use in your code like this

```
a = split:ReadArgument( "(.-)%s" )
b = split:ReadArgument( "tx=(%a+)" )
```

And so on.